# Does daily software development enhance the cognitive capacity of a person?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Software Development is an intense activity which requires using most of one's cognitive capacity. When programmers develop a software, they usually make an abstract understanding of the task which most of the time the tasks are composed of multi-layered structure --  considering the server-side to the user-interface aspects of the software. The process of making the software continues for weeks or months until the software is done.

My question is, does daily software development enhance the cognitive capacity of a person? Let's say compared to a typical office clerk doing paper works most of the time.

Comment: Use it or lose it applies for sure on cognitive abilities. Whether it is creating software, tinkering on experimental data analysis, diagnosing ill patients. writing journal articles or managing a team of folks on the work floor.

Comment: As Chris points out above, using skills makes them stronger, so probably.  But the real question is, which cognitive capacities?  compared to what? Obviously regular software development tends to increase software development skills, but does that generalize to other tasks? How is that generalization different from that which might happen from say, daily HR work? daily academic research? daily language self-study?

Comment: Voted to close because, as @Krysta argued, the question is too broad.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr See the new edits

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo I still believe it is too broad. I believe it would help if you'd refine 'cognitive capacity', as Krysta pointed out earlier.